# How to make android use my java file instead of a file on android.jar?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-source, android-sdk-tools

Let's say I want my own edittext. Extending isn't giving me full control, I want to duplicate the class and make some changes. I put the class in the same package as the original edittext i.e. android.text

Now when it runs, it takes the edittext.class located in the android.jar sdk.
How to make it take my edittext?

Comment: You can't... why do you not put into another package

Comment: It is like creating a new framework. But what is the problem in extending, (overriding the existing functionality)?

Comment: I want to use a few private methods. Tried extending, requiring more.

Comment: I want this class to be specific : SpannableStringBuilder.

I want android to take this class from my code and the rest of the classes from its framework.jar

pls help

Comment: I'm really confused. It sounds like you want to replace EditText *in android* and not in your own application. So you want to replace EditText on your device and have all applications on the device use your new EditText? Or do you want to build a new version of AOSP which has changes to EditText?

Comment: I want my project to use my own edittext.java

Rest of the files must be used from the jar itself. Is this possible?